# how to find regex after a dot or space but take only the string

Tags: regex

i want my regex to find "sometext" after dot or a space, but to take only the sometext. It is essential not to use $, because there can be text after "sometext", that i don't want to use.
examples:

1. hello sometext -> i want to get sometext, without "hello "
2. .sometext -> i want to find only sometext, without the dot
3. sup sometext this is a message -> i want to get only "sometext" without "sup " and " this is a message"

i used this regex, there is a small part missing, that excludes the space & dot after finding the regex, what should i add?

```
[(?<=\.)||(?<=\s)]sometext
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=[\s.])sometext
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V60uK5/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?<=[\s.])`: Lookbehind expression to assert we have dot or whitespace at previous position
- `sometext`: match literal text `sometext`

Lookbehind is **zero width assertion** that only asserts but doesn't match.

Your regex has a lookbehind with an extra `|` and that too inside `[ ... ]` which is interpreted as a character class.

Comment: yeah, but it still include the space and the dot, and if sometext has any thing at the end of it, it won't capure it for example:
.sometext2, i want to capture sometext, but not the dot or the 2

Comment: No, it won't include dot or whitespace in the match. Check demo link. Only matched text is in blue color.

Comment: Also if you want to match `sometext2` then make it clear in question. btw just removing `\b` will let it match `sometext` from `sometext2`. (See updated)

Comment: you are right, i didn't saw the [] brackets with the space and dot, that solved my problem, thank you!